# Includes() returns false value even though the array contains the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, range, include

In this custom code we have created a range from 150 to 210 which became an array. Afterwards we wanted to check whether a specific value is included in the previously created array but even though the value is clearly in the created array the includes() returns false. I cannot figure out why this is the case, could you please help me out with this?

```
function range(start, end, step = 1) {
    const len = Math.floor((end - start) / step) + 1
    return Array(len).fill().map((_, idx) => start + (idx * step))
  }
let sliderInterval = [];
sliderInterval.push(range(180 - 30,180 + 30,5))
console.log(sliderInterval.includes(180));
```

Comment: No, `sliderInterval` only contains one array. `180` is not an array. Did you mean `sliderInterval.push(...range(180 - 30,180 + 30,5))`?

Comment: `range()` returns an array, as you say; why do you `.push()` the array onto *another* array?

Comment: You can do `let sliderInterval = [...range(180 - 30,180 + 30,5)];` instead of `push()`

Comment: When i put the ... to my code it gave the right answer, thank you for that! I'm just starting with JS and in Python that two should be the same. I mean in Python these two are the same result wise so i assumed this is a correct way in JS too.
A = np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])])
B = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

But thank you again, problem got fixed! :)

Comment: @VandaNagy Numpy arrays are _very_ different from JavaScript arrays; the way operators work in Python is also very different.

Comment: that's not Python itself making that work the way you're used to, but the Numpy library. The Python language equivalent to your JS question is the [difference between extend and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)